# How to learn how files are connected to each other, routing,database connection in software development?

Tags: programming, web-development, app-development

These are the things in backend that confuse me a lot.
https://github.com/Lucifergene/Docker-Mern

Let's take this code for example.
Say I'm in server folder.

I can't understand how config models routes and index.js relate to each other. And how do I write one?

Even for client part,  I've trouble in understanding how files relate to each other.

For example, I'm here. https://github.com/Lucifergene/Docker-Mern/tree/master/client/app

I've tough time understanding how those files connect to each other. (I've done a MERN course worth 90 hrs already from a bootcamp).

I had to quit web development altogether and get some other job just because of this. But now, I am reigniting my desire to learn backend development as I'm not really a frontend person.

I've few project ideas as well.

1. CS Notes selling site for my country.
2. blog website
3. Reminder in calendar.
4. Video watched percentage calculator from a playlist. Like in udemy.
5. Another blog where anyone can create an account and post.
6. Locally hosted book search engine for pdf files. Like google books.

These are some of the project ideas of software development. Some are web, some are desktop based while some are android based.

I just shared this so that it could help users in answering the question.

Comment: (Know too little about MERN to say anything useful but...) Do you need to dive into MERN and docker at the same time? Clearly for professionals, comtainerized would make deploys easier. But you're not there yet

Comment: I'm just talking about MERN in this case. This was just an example.

Comment: This question is not specific enough to answer. There is not one solution to learning something (except for effort, time, practice, spaced learning, …).